# Prove $A_4\not< GL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Please prove $A_4$ can't be embedded in $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$

I know that $A_4=\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^3=(ab)^3=1\rangle$. Therefore, I've tried to match the generators with the matices and failed.
I came across another similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702789/show-that-q-8-cant-be-embedded-in-m-2-times-2-mathbbr-as-a-group/702794#702794) on the website concerning  $Q_8$ and $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, but I am not quite sure whether it can be applied to this. Ideas will also be appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with representation theory?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft No, I am a beginner of abstract algebra. This is a part of my homework.  Some reference will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume we have matrices $A,B\in GL_2(\Bbb C)$ with $A^2=B^3=(AB)^3=1$ (but $A\ne1$, $B\ne 1$). Then the minimal polynomial of $A$ is either $X^2-1$ or $X+1$, so that up to conjugation /  change of basis, 
$$\tag1 A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\text{ or }A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$
But we know that 
$$ \det A=\det A^3\det B^3=\det(AB)^3=1,$$
so only the second case is possible.
The minimal polynomial of $B$ must be of degree $\le 2$, a divisor of $X^3-1$, and not $X-1$. We conclude that it is $X^2+X+1$. But then $AB$ is annihilated by the polynomial $X^ 2-X+1$, which means that $AB$ is of order $6$, not $3$.