# Reference for "every finite subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ is conjugate to a finite subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$"

Tags: linear-algebra

In this question ([Finite Subgroups of GL(n,R)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58476/finite-subgroups-of-gln-r)), the OP mentioned that every finite subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ is conjugate to a finite subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$. Is there a reference for this fact?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is now asked on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/221351/reference-for-a-linear-algebra-result (It might be worth adding link to your post, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088).)